# How to put variable into find.element?

Tags: java, testing, selenium, webdriver

I need to track element by `data-user` which has to a variable. Here's my code, which works:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[data-user='Caroline']")).click();
```

I add:

```
String UserName = "Caroline";
```

And edit `find.Element`. Here's what I've tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[data-user=""+ UserName]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[data-user=''+ UserName]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[data-user="'+ UserName +'"]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[data-user='"+ UserName +"']")).click();
```

But these don't work. Any ideas for this one?

EDIT:

The case is to click a particular search result 'Caroline' as search results appear dynamically when I enter another letter to the search text.

Answer (score 1):

The bottom one should work if the cssSelector method can take an arguement split like that. I know that XPath can, so try:

```
driver.findElement(By.XPath("//div[@data-user='"+ UserName +"']")).click();
```

As a side note however, using an ID is always preferable to css or xpath. Or ask the dev to give the items you interect with a class you can hook in to as described [here](http://csswizardry.com/2015/03/more-transparent-ui-code-with-namespaces/#qa-namespaces-qa-), that way they should never change.

Comment: Would need to see the html containing the element. What you where doing should work.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, this should work without any issue

```
String UserName = "Caroline";
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[data-user='"+ UserName +"']")).click();
```